# CSS3 : Box shadow just like in the image

Tags: html, css

I have an image. I want to have the box shadow just like in the image.

I have tried below code.

[image: Box Shadow Image]

```css
.main_div{
  height:260px;
  width:300px;
  
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div"></div>
```

I don't want box-shadow to top.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add multiple box-shadow, as you don't want that at top so you could style each side as below,

Syntax for `box-shadow`,

```
box-shadow:offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color
```

```css
.main_div {
  height: 260px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 10px -5px rgba(67, 176, 238, 1), 10px 12px 10px -5px rgba(67, 176, 238, 1), -10px 12px 10px -5px rgba(67, 176, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div"></div>
```

Comment: i don't want box-shadow to top.

Comment: @Rishi Check updated codes and please do add vendor prefixes, I removed that while editing your codes. Add that for browser support.

Comment: @Rishi Check this jsFiddle if you don't want to style at each side of box, https://jsfiddle.net/xg6d8bb8/

Answer (score 0):

try this; hope it works for you;

```
.main_div {
height: 260px;
width: 300px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgb(67, 176, 238);
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it does not match with my image that i have posted.

Comment: try this,box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. You can change opacity to your liking

```css
.main-main{
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: #bcc0c6;
    }
    .main_div{
      background-color: white;
      height:260px;
      width:300px;
      
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(224, 13, 34,1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(224, 13, 34,1);
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(224, 13, 34,1);
    }
```

```html
<br />
<div class="main-main">
    <div class="main_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want box-shadow to top.

Comment: I got confused now :) I changed code a little bit, but still don't understand what do you mean by box-shadow to top? There is no shadow at top if div

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
.main_div{
    height:260px;
    width:300px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(67, 176, 238);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(32, 79, 182);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used your image (displayed at the top) and I also wrapped your div in order to set a background color similar to yours. I think the result (displayed at the bottom) is quite close to the provided image:

```css
.main_div_wrap {
  background-color:#eff2f4;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.main_div {
  background-color:#ffffff;
  height: 260px;
  width: 350px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 12px 0px rgb(197, 224, 246);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 12px 0px rgb(197, 224, 246);
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 12px 0px rgb(197, 224, 246);
}
What about this?
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbltS.png" />
<div class="main_div_wrap">
  <div class="main_div"></div>
</div>
```